# is the given structure a group

Tags: group-theory

is the below given structure a group??
[     *    e a b c d f g

```
  e    e a b c d f g
  a    a b e g c d f
  b    b e a f g c d
  c    c d f a e g b
  d    d f g e a b c
  f    f g c d b a e
  g    g c d b f e a     ]  if yes, then {e,a,b} will be subgroup, correct?
```

then wont it violate Lagrange's theorem. Please I am new to group theory.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you're right: this can't be a group, because if it were, then $\{e, a, b\}$ would be a subgroup, which violates Lagrange's theorem. Note how useful Lagrange is here: it would be really frustrating to check by hand which group axiom is violated in the above structure!

Answer (score 4):

The composition is not associative, because
$$
(a\cdot b)\cdot c=c\neq d=a\cdot (b\cdot c).
$$
Hence the structure table does not define a group.

Answer (score 1):

Or, using a bit more theory: $7$ is prime, so a group of order $7$ must be cyclic. But this group manifestly isn't.

Comment: Which is again relying on Lagrange's theorem...

Comment: @DietrichBurde It is pretty difficult to do group theory without Lagrange's theorem, I concur.

Comment: That's true of course!

Answer (score 1):

To give a bit more info on this structure:

- It is a [magma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magma_(algebra)), because the operation is closed in $\{e,a,b,c,d,f,g\}$.
- It is a [quasigroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasigroup), because every element appears in every row and column exactly once.
- It is a [loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_(algebra)), because $e\ast x=x\ast e=x$ for each $x$.
- It is not a left [Bol loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bol_loop), because $a\ast(b\ast(a\ast c))=c\ne g=(a\ast(b\ast a))\ast c$.
- It is not a right Bol loop, because $((c\ast a)\ast b)\ast a=c\ne d=c\ast ((a\ast b)\ast a)$.
- (It follows from either of the last two that it is not a [group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)).)